# gradlew buildDocker fails with Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, jhipster

after running "jhipster" and creating a monolithic application, I try to run it in Docker according to the manual, and get an error message of the following kind:

`What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
 com.github.dockerjava.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect`

after some googling, I sort of figured out that with Docker Toolbox (boy is contemporary IT field fucked) one actually has to connect to Docker Engine running on different IP, so I've set an environment variable like this:

`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376` I get a `DockerException (no message)` error

Answer (score 1):

It is docker daemon which has to be open to accept non-TLS connection from mvn/gradle build processes. Open Docker window to update settings as shown in attached image[image]

Comment: do you know how to do the same via docker quickstart terminal please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think this should be also reflected on the JHipster documentation page: with Docker Toolbox one needs to have 3 (THREE) environment variable set as follows:

`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:/Users/<your-name>/.docker/machine/certs
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1`

You can check if it's properly setup by running `docker images` in the same shell where you run `gradlew` command

Comment: Please submit a PR to the documentation https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io